# How do you ream a conical bore when making a woodwind instrument?

Tags: instruments, woodwinds, instrument-making

There isn't a lot of documentation on how reaming woodwind instruments works, and how you do it. Is there a specific method to making a smooth conical bore, like in that of an oboe? I've seen people use D-bits, but I don't understand how you can make a conical bore with that.

Comment: Tapered reamers have been around for a very long time - especially in engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to  the Internet,  questions like this are easily answered.  For example,  info on [clarinet](http://www.madehow.com/Volume-3/Clarinet.html) :

> 2 When the manufacturer receives the billets, workers inspect the lot.
>   Then skilled workers place the billets on a borer, which drills a hole
>   lengthwise through the center of each piece. The diameter and shape of
>   this hole, called the bore of the clarinet, is crucial to determining
>   the tone of the instrument. The bore may be drilled in a straight
>   cylinder, or the cylinder may be slightly tapered. After the bore is
>   drilled, the body pieces are turned on a lathe. The rectangular
>   billets become smooth, round, hollow cylinders. These cylinders are
>   then seasoned again.
>
> Read more: http://www.madehow.com/Volume-3/Clarinet.html#ixzz5i9KZ3aqM

There are some YouTube videos showing oboe-reaming in a machine shop.